# Error with ActiveX and MCVE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

In my search of the error of the return of S_OK and not S_FALSE (see my previous message), I have made a very small sever with only one method wich send S_FALSE (HResult type), unfortunatly I have an error with the small client program: The project TestTest.exe has send the exception class EOleSysError with the message 'variable type invalid' (it's the instruction `Return:=coll.Method` which raise the error).
Any idea?
The .ridl
[image]
the server code:

```
function TTest1.Method: HResult;
begin
  Result:=S_FALSE;
end;
```

and the client code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  coll:variant;
  Return:HResult;
begin
  coll:= CreateOLEObject('Project.Test1');
  Return:=coll.Method;
  if Return=S_FALSE then showmessage('OK') else showmessage('ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
end;
```

for the full problem I have made an MCVE:
the server: [enter link description here](http://www.etoiles-a-bleau/transfert/Server.zip)
the client: [enter link description here](http://www.etoiles-a-bleau/transfert/TestTest.zip)

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the parameter 'value' of type `HRESULT`. You can delete that parameter: the method will already return `HRESULT`. If you want to test with a parameter, try changing 'value' to `BSTR` [in] and pass any string there. It should work.

```
Return:=coll.Method('place the parameter string here');
```

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunatly your are false, if I remove the parameter 'Value' of type `HResult`, the function `Method` become a procedure. The test I want to make is especially with the type `HRESULT` because my problem is with this parameter.

Comment: @michastro We are nearly two weeks in to this investigation, and still there is no MCVE. Why not? I'm betting that you are exporting `register` calling convention functions. But if you won't show an MCVE, all we can do is guess. Please trust me that I know what I am talking about. I know how to get solutions to problems. You make an MCVE, we give you a definitive answer, you go away happy. It's really that simple.

Comment: I am sorry David but I have posted a MCVE 6 days ago, and nobody has answered something!

Comment: We need this in the question and not an off site link

Comment: @michastro: No, you didn't. You first posted a link to an off-site download, and then you posted a large code dump. Neither of those are an MCVE - the code dump is hardly **minimal*.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you Stuck with `HRESULT` to return value , why you don't create `HRESULT` METHOD with parameter  `value, type : long , modifier : in` then return what ever you want .

Comment: I haven't the choice, I want to test the bad return of `Next` and `Reset` in an IEnumVariant, so I want to make a copy of theses functions to find why S_FALSE is changed in S_OK.